# Managing flame direction (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, smoke-simulation, fire

I have a fire on my scene and it goes upwards. I want it going in a horizontal direction. How can I achieve that? Changing Temperature Difference only flips direction in the vertical axis. [image: Flame]  [image: Domain settings] [image: Flow settings]

Comment: Wind force field can help with this issue but it is still unknown if it possible to control flame direction by flame settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Overview:

[image]

You can control flame direction by **Normals** from **Mesh** that is your **Flow** object. In this example I'm using **Circle** filled with **Triangle fan**.

### Mesh:

[image: mesh]

As I said before, simple **Circle**. You can check where **Normals** direction will go in **Edit Mode** > **Mesh Display tab** > **Normals**.

### Flow:

Now in **Flow** settings you'll need to turn on **Initial Velocity**. Set **Source** to **0** and **Normal** to something higher then **0**. This value will control the initial flame speed. By now flame will be rising but we can change it in **Domain** settings easily.

[image: Flow]

### Domain:

In **Domain** settings you will need to set **Temp. Diff.** to **0**. This will make flame straight. Higher value = faster smoke rising.

[image]